# VBScript RegRead returning extra characters at the end

Tags: vbscript, registry

I'm trying to read the value from a windows registry Key by the following code in VBScript:

```
Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox WSHShell.RegRead(strRegistryKey)
```

The value returned is somehow the right value set in the registry and some others odd characters concatenated at the end of the string:

Ex.:

**Value in the registry:** database_ora_TS36

**Value returned:** database_ora_TS36Ž#

The key type is **REG_SZ**.

Does anybody know what can be happening?

Comment: What is the type of the key you're trying to read?

Comment: The key type is **REG_SZ**.

Comment: Do you see the same trailing characters when you read the value via WMI (`GetObject("winmgmts://./root/default:StdRegProv").GetStringValue(&h80000002, keyname, valuename, value) : WScript.Echo value`) or with `reg.exe` on the command line?

Comment: reg.exe in the command line returns the right value

Comment: What about the WMI command?